# Css transform translate cut drag image

Tags: html, transform, draggable

I have a target element that has a transform translate and draggable attribute.

**Edit : This is part of a bigger application and I have to keep the transform:translate.**

Because of the transform, when dragging, the drag image is cut as the transform is not apply to it. How can I retain the correct drag image while applying a transform translate ?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bikiew/4dLt74z2/

```
<div class="item" draggable="true"></div>
.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-30px, 0px);
}
```

Is there a solution with pure CSS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4dLt74z2/30/

try using a

```
margin-left:-30px;
```

in place of the transform. It will have the same effect as a

```
transform: translate(-30px, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot remove the transform, it is needed for my application.